# Isolate connected_components

Tags: filter, networkx, subgraph, connected-components

I have following networkx graph excerpt:

[image]

Following functions were executed to explore the structure of connected components, as I have a sparse network with lots of singular connections:

```
nx.number_connected_components(G) 
>>> 702

list(nx.connected_components(G))
>>> [{120930, 172034},
 {118787, 173867, 176202},
 {50376, 151561}, 
...]
```

**Question:** How can I restrict my whole graph visualization to connected_components with *equal or more than three* nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
graphs = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G))
list_subgraphs=[items for i in graphs for items in i if len(i)>=3]
F=G.subgraph(list_subgraphs)
```

Creating a flat list of the subgraphs with components greater than 3 nodes lets say!

Answer (score 2):

We can create a subgraph containing the components with equal or more than three nodes:

```
s = G.subgraph(
    set.union(
        *filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3, nx.connected_components(G))
    )
)
```

Now you just need to visualize this subgraph `s`.

We might need to make a copy instead of a `SubGraph` view, in that case, `s = s.copy()` will make a copy from the subgraph.